# How would light look like if you travelled at the same speed as it does in water?

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, refraction

How would light look like if you travelled at the same speed as it does in for example water? Could you see it?

Answer (score 1):

Water refractive index is around 4/3, which yields a lightspeed of .75 *c*.

At that speed, you would experience a significant color [*shift*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift#Redshift_formulae), with objects moving towards you becoming bluer and objects left behind becoming redder (actually, you would be able to "see" the infrared light from objects in front of you, possibly even some radio waves. Check out the formulae above and solve for perceived range of incoming photons in the visible octave).

So you would see something, just not the same something you'd see at rest.

Conversely, if you were to observe something moving with your same speed in the same direction - including yourself - you wouldn't notice anything.

In case I misunderstood the full import of the question, moving at .75c *in water* is an [exceedingly bad idea](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/).

Comment: Your answer assumes that the observer is moving relative to "objects in front of you" and "objects behind you", but the question is wide open to interpretation.  IMO, the word "travel" in any question that pertains to light or relativity is a red flag that may indicate deep misunderstanding on the part of the person who asked it.

Comment: @jameslarge what's wrong with the word travel, even Einstein used it.

Comment: I don't know what implications the word "travel" had for a German immigrant to the U.S.A. in the mid 20th century, but when I see it used in questions on this forum, they seem always to be like the one above:  Questions that ask, "What if _X_ travelled some percent of/at/faster than the speed of light...", without ever saying, "...relative to _Y_."